# How to convert URL in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

my framework is `laravel 5.2`, my website is **Buy plane ticket**.

`from`: Tehran, Imam Khomeini Intl (IKA), Iran.

`to`: London (LON), United Kingdom.

`date`: flight date.

`adult`: 2 people, `child`: 1 people, `infant`: 0 people.

current URL is:

```
http://localhost:8000/flights?from=IKA&to=LON&date=2016-11-25&adult=2&child=1&infant=0
```

I want to change this URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/flights/IKA-LON/2016-11-25/2-1-0
```

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a more rigid alternative, your route could be registered like this:

```
Route::get('flights/{from}-{to}/{date}/{people}', function ($from, $to, $date, $people) {
    list($adults, $children, $infants) = explode('-', $people);
    dd([$from, $to, $date, $adults, $children, $infants]);
})->where([
    'date'=>'\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}',
    'people'=>'[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+'
]);
```

This ensures your route contains the proper formatting before being recognized as valid.

Comment: Thank you so much, this URL is One-way-trip but if the user chose return trip, this Route is: Route::get('/flights/{from}-{to}/{go-date}/{return-date}/{ad‌​ult}-{child}-{infant‌​}', ...); What should I do?

Comment: Open a new question with these requirements. As it stands, we've all answered your original question.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can not ask for up to 90 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Your route will looks like

```
Route::get('/flights/{from}-{to}/{date}/{adult}-{child}-{infant}', 'YourController@details');
```

Controller

```
public function details($from, $to, $date, $adult, $child, $infant)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this URL is One-way-trip but if the user chose return trip, this Route is: Route::get('/flights/{from}-{to}/{go-date}/{return-date}/{adult}-{child}-{infant}', 'YourController@details'); What should I do?

Comment: You can using optional params like {return-date?}

Answer (score 1):

First step is to make a `route` for you new url

```
Route::get('flights/{from}-{to}/{date}/{adult}-{child}-{infant}', 'MyController@Index');
```

Next you need to read the url content in your controller

Comment: Thank you so much, this URL is One-way-trip but if the user chose return trip, this Route is: Route::get('/flights/{from}-{to}/{go-date}/{return-date}/{ad‌​ult}-{child}-{infant‌​}', 'MyController@Index'); What should I do?

Comment: I would add extra slugs like this /{way}/{return_date}, where /s means single way or /r means return ticket, /and_return_date, if /s then return date should be null